# Catch the login_check on Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, propel

I need that when a user logs in, to catch his/her username and save an history of logins, but I don't know how to intercept that information.

Comment: Hi there. Just so you know, good questions here generally require an explanation of what you have tried so far, and requests for urgent responses are discouraged. It looks like you have an answer to help start your research and testing, so perhaps give that a go? You can always ask a new question if you get stuck on a specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you only want to save the successful logins, so for that here is the solution:
You need to create a service what extends AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface and implement the function there. That is called after the successful login.

The other thing what you need to do is add the service in the firewall:

```
main:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            provider: your_login_provider
            login_path: /
            success_handler: id_of_your_succeslogin_service
```

Comment: I did it using rediection with a default_target_path and the failure_path

Comment: If you will read about this more, you will see that my answer is the right way, not rely on the routes. This is why the event handlers are there in symfony and there there especially at the login.